# Any way to create custom slot values in Alexa Lambda function?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently making a skill which has a custom slot type called "products", but this skill will be used by many different sellers that will have different products, so I cannot know ahead of time which values will populate this slot. If I define an empty slot type called "products", is there a way to fill the slot type with values IN the Lambda NodeJS code? All I would need to do is make a HTTP request to that specific person's database.

Or possibly could there be a way to define a pseudo-slot in the lambda code with words that Alexa will associate with a slot type?

Answer (score 0):

I think the slot `must` be defined in the Intent Schema, and you would have to provide the list of possible names of products for that slot. Possible solution would be to use the `LITERAL` slot type.

Comment: Wait, that's what I want! I can define it and leave it empty and then populate it within the lambda function? How??

Comment: You could use the `LITERAL` slot type and then do all the logic inside your intent handler. I access the slot's value like this when using Node.js `this.event.request.intent.slots.Term.value` where `Term` is the name of my slot.